# Proof-question: Pullback-bundle is a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I refer to the following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2985228/prove-the-pullback-bundle-is-a-vector-bundle). In Creo's answer $\psi$ is used as the trivialization. I have problems verifying that $\psi$ indeed fulfills the conditions of a trivialization, especially that it is a bijection in the first place. The problem seems to be the injectivity of $\psi$ or rather of $\text{pr}_2 \circ \phi$. Why would the latter be injective?

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Comment: @Deane Yes I did. However, I am fairly new to the topic and I did not know the definitions of frames or sections. So, I did not really understand the ideas. But, even if I did, the paper I am working with uses the same proof idea described by Creo and I want to understand this in particular.

Comment: For each $n \in N$, $\operatorname{pr}_2\circ\phi$ is injective because it is a linear isomorphism from the fiber $f^*E_n = E_{f(n)} = \pi^{-1}(f(n))$ to $\R^k$.

Comment: A section of $E$ over an open $U \subset M$ is simply a map $s: U \rightarrow E$ such that $s(m) \in \pi^{-1}(M)$. A frame over $U$ consists of $k$ sections $s_1, \dots, s_k$ such that for each $m \in U$, $(s_1(m), \dots, s_k(m))$ is a basis of $\pi^{-1}(E)$. A frame is equivalent to a trivialization because, any such frame defines a trivialization  \begin{align*} U\times\mathbb{R}^k &\rightarrow E\\ (m,(w^1, \dots, w^k)) &\mapsto w^1s_1(m)+\cdots+w^ks_k(m) \end{align*} and vice versa.